# Why is the falling edge slower than the rising edge?

Tags: amplifier, high-frequency

I have a radiation sensor connected to an amplifier and then to an oscilloscope. This is the circuit:

[image]

The radiation sensor (an LGAD) is connected straight into the "In" terminal, few millimeters away from the circuit. The amplifier is basically two stages based on the [PSA4-5043+](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=PSA4-5043%2B) with a 3 dB attenuator in between. For some reason the falling edge is about half as fast as I would expect it to be. This is how a typical signal looks like:

[image]

I expect the falling edge to have the same (or similar) slope as the rising edge.

This is a typical signal from the same radiation detector but connected to a different amplifier which behaves as expected:

[image]

This other amplifier is a single transistor common emitter configuration built with a [BFP840FESD](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf/rf-transistor/low-noise-rf-transistors/bfp840fesd/) followed by a single stage [SPF5189Z](https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/SPF5189Z) amplifier. Don't pay attention to the amplitude as this it is random depending on the energy deposited by the radiation in the sensor. But look at the falling edge, here it is similar to the rising edge.

What are possible reasons for this? It does not look like a bandwidth effect...

Comment: How the radiation sensor does what it does is important.

Comment: Data sheet links to the "good" amplifier and the "bad" amplifier are needed along with the schematic of the good amplifier.

Comment: We also need to know what kind of radiation sensor you're using. A Geiger-Müller tube?

Comment: Just a note that may or may not have anything at all to do with it. But I see a fairly linear decline. For capacitance this suggests a constant current. Easily achieved and perhaps worth looking for. For resistance this suggests a constant rate of change of current. Easily achieved with a fixed voltage across inductance. I see inductors there. Might also be worth a look-see. What's your standard for the 2nd graph? How was it produced?

Comment: The radiation sensor is a silicon radiation sensor. LGAD to be precise. I will now add links to the datasheets of the amplifiers in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the good case I think you have less gain. The common emitter should be about 0 dB and the second stage about 18 dB. In the bad case you have about 33. You say to not pay attention to the voltage magnitudes but I wonder if in the higher gain case you are saturating the output of the second stage. The psa... amp has an output 1 dB compression point of about 19 dBm (into 50 Ohms). You don't say if you are loading the output, but I assume you are. 19 dBm (50) is 6 dBV RMS or about -3 dBv peak. which is .707 V. The output shape is reminiscent of an amp that is recovering from an overload. If you output pulses are at least slightly smaller that .707 than my hunch is off.

Comment: The pulse I posted as example is 100 mV if you see the plot. This effect happens for all the signals, no matter the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

"single transistor common emitter configuration".  That only actively sinks current but uses a pullup for sourcing current.  With a reactive load, that will cause asymmetric rise times.